# Files Not Renaming in Windows Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

Please Help! I have a batch file that performs the following tasks:
 1) renames a counter field
 2) creates two variables that will be used later to rename two separate files
 3) Opens SQL*Plus and starts an Oracle Script which starts two separate stored procedures
 4) Moves and renames the subsequent spooled files from both procedures

The first spooled file moves and renames with no problem. The second one (which has a job that is more labor intensive) does not move or rename. I have tried adding a TIMEOUT and making sure that the folders have the right permissions. Still nothing. My code for the batch file and the Oracle script are attached below.

Batch File

---

```
@echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set filename="E:\Transfers\XXX\prod_directory\pullsched_seq2.dat"
 if exist "%filename%" del "%filename%"
 for /f %%A in (E:\Transfers\XXX\prod_directory\pullsched_seq.dat) do (
 set num=%%A
 set /a num+=1
 echo !num!>>"%filename%" 
 )
 set newnum=!num!
 set newproc=schedule%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%.dat
 del "E:\Transfers\XXX\prod_directory\pullsched_seq.dat"
 rename "E:\Transfers\XXX\prod_directory\pullsched_seq2.dat" "pullsched_seq.dat"
 rem start Oracle Script
 E:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN\SQLPLUSW.EXE
 logon/password @database @C:\Schedule\pullschedule0325.sql
 move C:\Schedule\schedule_today.txt E:\Transfers\ftpadmin\archive\schedule\%newnum%
 (this move works)
 move C:\Schedule\schedule_today2.txt E:\Transfers\XXX\output_directory\%newproc%
 (this one does not)
```

Oracle Script (@C:\Schedule\pullsched0325.sql)

---

```
 rem @C:\Schedule\pullsched0325.sql
 set term off
 set feedback off
 set verify off
 set echo off
 set heading off
 set serveroutput on size 1000000
 set linesize 174
 spool C:\Schedule\schedule_today.txt
 execute SBT_SCHEDULE_LOAD_DATA
 spool C:\Schedule\schedule_today2.txt
 execute SBT_SCHEDULE_LOAD_SCHEDULES
 exit
 /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um - you are aware, I take it that time and date formats are not usinversal - they depend on local settings. Without knowing the precise details of your local settings, we're guessing.

I'd suggest you simply

```
echo +%newproc%+
```

after `set`ting it. The `+` is just to show where any spaces are - no magic.

If the resultant string can potentially contain spaces, then

```
move C:\Schedule\schedule_today2.txt "E:\Transfers\XXX\output_directory\%newproc%"
```

should cure the problem.

OR

```
set "newproc=%newproc: =0%"
move C:\Schedule\schedule_today2.txt "E:\Transfers\XXX\output_directory\%newproc%"
```

should cure it more - replacing any space in `newproc` with a `0`.

If your format is incorrect - like for instance you are using suppressed-leading-spaces with your hours, then it could be that the resultant string in `newproc` contains invalid filename characters like `:`.

All depends on the detail of your date/time format.

Of course, your destination directory `"E:\Transfers\XXX\output_directory\"` exists...?

Comment: Magoo - You've done it!!  That fixed my problem.  I usually do my testing in the afternoon and late morning.  The jobs run first thing in the morning.  I would have had a hard time catching that.  THANKS!!